# Facebook/ Messenger

Tags: facebook

So recently something has happened and I want to reach out to someone I can view their profile and see they’re profile pics, and their most recent one but when I try to message them it says that the option couldn’t be done and I don’t know why? ( btw me and this person aren’t friends on Facebook) (This person was also using messenger not to long ago)